# Could not read JSON in Spring Cloud Stream With Kafka Test

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I have a simple application which receives an message and writes to another topic by using spring cloud stream and kafka. I am trying to write unit test according to some tutorial but I am getting an error while sending the message. According to message, it cannot read the JSON.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private Processor processor;

    @Autowired
    private MessageCollector messageCollector;


    @Test
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void testWriting() {

        MyRecord myRecord= getDummyRecord(); // getting dummy MyRecord object

        Message<MyRecord> message = MessageBuilder.withPayload(myRecord).setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, getDummyKey()).build();
        processor.input().send(message);

        Message<MyRecord> receivedMessage = (Message<MyRecord>) messageCollector.forChannel(processor.output()).poll();


    }

}
```

Error which I am getting is :

> Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 'WeatherRecordRaw': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
>    at [Source: (String)"MyRecord(....)

How can I fix that, I do not have problem in application, only in test.

Comment: You need to show what `myRecord` looks like.

Comment: What do you mean exactly ? It is simple POJO class.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending directly to the input channel; the binder gets the data from the source (RabbitMQ, Kafka etc) and sends it to the channel for conversion.

The input channel is expecting to get JSON, not a POJO; it will then convert the JSON back to the POJO.

Use a Jackson `ObjectMapper` to convert the POJO to a `byte[]` containing a JSON representation.

Comment: thank you very much!! very hard mistake!!)) You save me

Comment: you need use output stream instead of input